# Calculate covariance of two bivariate normal random variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, bivariate-distributions

I'm reading Modern Mathematical Statistics with Applications and I don't know how to get the covariance of $\rho$ from $X$ and $Y$ in Example 6.16:
[image: image of problem description]

Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [linearity of covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations).
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)
&= \operatorname{Cov}(Z_1, \rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_2)
\\
&= \rho \operatorname{Cov}(Z_1, Z_1) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \operatorname{Cov}(Z_1, Z_2).
\end{align}
Can you finish from here?

Comment: ok, so Cov(Z_1,Z_2)=0 and and Cov(Z_1,Z_1)=1, thanks